# Find duplicate text in different columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I'm looking for a function or a macro which will do the following

Say in the below table, If I wanted to identify the unique number of occurrences of the text in different columns/rows.. how can I find?

```
bat ball boy    bat ball boy     cat bat boy
bat ball boy    ball cat boy     bat ball boy
cat bat boy     ball python cat
```

Comment: Easiest way to get to results is use excels feature called remove duplicates on "Data"-tab in ribbon..

Comment: show us what your desired output would be...

Comment: Downvoting with regrets: a good answer came in on the same day, and you did not reply, vote or accept.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that you are looking for some sort of pseudo-COUNTUNIQUE() function.

[image]

The formulas for A6, E1 and E6 are,

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A1:A5<>"")/COUNTIF(A1:A5,A1:A5&""))
=SUMPRODUCT((A1:D1<>"")/COUNTIF(A1:D1,A1:D1&""))
  ... and,
=SUMPRODUCT((A1:D5<>"")/COUNTIF(A1:D5,A1:D5&""))
```

A6 can be filled right; E1 can be filled down. The non-blank unique count for the A1:D5 block is in E6.